# How to resolve Bulk Insert truncation error

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with this error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 58 (kol57).
```

I loaded files before without problem.
Current insert:

```
BULK
INSERT #CSVTable
FROM 'd:\data\bb3.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
CODEPAGE =  'ACP'
)
GO
```

Table was created for first column with varchar(100), and all other varchar(5) (tried int, not helping)

Tried RAW for Codepage, and few terminators - \r, \n, 0x0A
With all of those i have multiple errors like first one on every row

With \r\n or \n\r only one - on first row

I also tried adding more columns with no effect

File is simple and looks like that on n++:

```
pyt1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;1
pyt2;1;1;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
```

With CRLF on every line ending
Whats wrong here?

Comment: The obvious question is: what is in row 1, column 58? and what data type is the column you are trying to load into?

Comment: 58 column is last symbol in row pyt1

its simple: 1

tried to varchar(5) or int

Comment: The error suggest the row terminator is other than what you've specified. Open the file in Notepad++ and select View-->Show Symbol-->Show End of Line to verify it's actually `CRLF`.

Comment: @DanGuzman
Its exactly that(screen): [link](https://ibb.co/WGh3QJg)

Comment: It seems the `ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'` is not recognized for some reason. Try specifying the hex codes instead: `ROWTERMINATOR = '0X0D0A'`.

Comment: Unfortunetly it not work also :(
Get a bunch of errors on every row
`Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 59 (kol58).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 59 (kol58).`

Comment: Have you tried generating a format file with bcp.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a persistent table somewhere from which you can create a BCP format file (you won't be able to use a #temp table for this), e.g.:

```sql
use StackOverflow
go
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.CSVTable;
CREATE TABLE dbo.CSVTable (
    Col01 varchar(100), Col02 varchar(5), Col03 varchar(5), Col04 varchar(5), Col05 varchar(5),
    Col06 varchar(5), Col07 varchar(5), Col08 varchar(5), Col09 varchar(5), Col10 varchar(5),
    Col11 varchar(5), Col12 varchar(5), Col13 varchar(5), Col14 varchar(5), Col15 varchar(5),
    Col16 varchar(5), Col17 varchar(5), Col18 varchar(5), Col19 varchar(5), Col20 varchar(5),
    Col21 varchar(5), Col22 varchar(5), Col23 varchar(5), Col24 varchar(5), Col25 varchar(5),
    Col26 varchar(5), Col27 varchar(5), Col28 varchar(5), Col29 varchar(5), Col30 varchar(5),
    Col31 varchar(5), Col32 varchar(5), Col33 varchar(5), Col34 varchar(5), Col35 varchar(5),
    Col36 varchar(5), Col37 varchar(5), Col38 varchar(5), Col39 varchar(5), Col40 varchar(5),
    Col41 varchar(5), Col42 varchar(5), Col43 varchar(5), Col44 varchar(5), Col45 varchar(5),
    Col46 varchar(5), Col47 varchar(5), Col48 varchar(5), Col49 varchar(5), Col50 varchar(5),
    Col51 varchar(5), Col52 varchar(5), Col53 varchar(5), Col54 varchar(5), Col55 varchar(5),
    Col56 varchar(5), Col57 varchar(5), Col58 varchar(5)
);
```

Then, in a Command Prompt, use the [bcp.exe utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) to create a format file:

```
bcp.exe "StackOverflow.dbo.CSVTable" format nul -fD:\data\bb3.fmt -c -t; -S(local) -T
```

You should then be able to import your data with `BULK INSERT` by referencing the format file:

```sql
BULK INSERT #CSVTable
FROM 'D:\data\bb3.csv'
WITH (
    FORMATFILE = 'D:\data\bb3.fmt'
    );

SELECT * FROM #CSVTable
```